# How to find which array element is not present in another

Tags: ruby

Here is the scenario

```ruby
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,5,6]
```

I would like to find out which elements of `b` are not present in `a`. I could use `include?` to check which ones are. But I am looking for something entirely opposite here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
> a - b
=> [1, 3]
> b - a
=> [5, 6]
```

(I can't quite tell which way you want to go.)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,5,6]
b - a #=> [5, 6]
```